# Can someone help me find a Mathematical documentary that aired on British television within the past 10 years about Leibniz?

Tags: reference-request

I have been searching for a documentary that aired on British television between around 2006 and 2012 which was centred around the German Mathematician, Gottfried Leibniz. All that I can remember about the show is that it discussed his dispute with Sir Isaac Newton regarding the invention of calculus, as well as a problem regarding a Brachistochrone curve. It also featured one of Leibniz's living relatives who appeared at the end of the show who was working in something media related. (obscure details, I know...)

I have eliminated two documentaries about Mathematics from my list including:

The Story of Maths (2008) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Maths
The Birth of Calculus (1986) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObPg3ki9GOI
I have tried doing extensive searches on Google and various websites such as the BBC to no avail. Can anyone remember what television programme I am referring to?

Thanks.

Comment: Did it talk about alchemy?

Comment: It's possible, I can't remember exactly, I don't think it painted Newton in the greatest light. The clearest thing I remember about it is that it highlighted the Newton-Leibniz Calculus controversy and suggested how it almost caused a "war" between Britain and Germany. The programme introduced the concept of calculus to the audience by explaining that the fastest way to roll a ball from one point to another on a ramp was by using a curved surface as opposed to a straight one. A distant relative of Leibniz was definitely interviewed at some point near the end of the show.

Comment: First thing that comes up in IMDB when searching for documentaries and Lebniz is this: [Spinoza and Leibniz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1046522/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that's not the one I'm thinking of. The documentary/television programme that I saw was definitely made in the 21st century.

Answer (score 1):

I think the BBC documentary you are talking about is [The Birth of Calculus (1986)](https://www.thetvdb.com/series/bbc-documentaries/episodes/4956673)